# i have problem with uv packer. How do i fix this uv? i click pack and it snap to the edge. I follow champfer zone tutorial

Tags: modeling, uv, uv-image-editor, texture-coordinates

[image]aa

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azkly.jpg)[image]

Comment: Could you please include some information about what you have tried so far, and what you did to get here? Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thx for helping. It fixed now. I just want it to be full uv mapping not snaped to the side. Just missed some mark seam

Comment: apply object scale in object mode